# Visual Studio Code: Starting in non debug mode stops in breakpoints and complains

Tags: nestjs, nodemon, vscode-debugger

I am using Visual Studio Code with nestjs and nodemon and I have the following configuration:

**package.json**

```json
"start:dev": "nodemon --config nodemon.json",
"start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",
```

**nodemon.json**

```json
{
    "watch": ["src"],
    "ext": "ts,gql",
    "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts","src/testing/*"],
    "env": {}
}
```

**nodemon-debug.json**

```json
{
    "watch": ["src"],
    "ext": "ts,gql",
    "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts","src/testing/*"],
    "env": {},
    "exec": "node --inspect -r ts-node/register src/main.ts"
}
```

I also set Auto Attach toggle in VS Code with

```
Debug: Toggle Auto Attach
```

and now I can see and toggle auto attach from the status bar.

[image]

If I leave Auto Attach **ON** and run `npm start:dev` (non debug mode), every time it reaches an active breakpoint, it stops on it and complains `Could not load source '/src/...': Unable to retrieve source content.`. Also vs code shows the debug toolbar.

[image]

If I toggle auto attach to off, everything works ok.

My question is: Is this the expected behaviour and I need to toggle on or off if I will debug or not? Should it not to do that automatically, being smart enough to know if it is in debug mode?